# Jupyter notebooks as Kedro node

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-pipeline, kedro

How can I use a Jupyter Notebook as a node in Kedro pipeline? This is different from [converting functions from Jupyter Notebooks into Kedro nodes](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/10_tools_integration/02_ipython.html?highlight=executer#converting-functions-from-jupyter-notebooks-into-kedro-nodes). What I want to do is using the full notebook as the node.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is technically possible (via [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line), for example), this is strongly discouraged for [multiple reasons](https://blog.valohai.com/leveling-up-your-ml-code-from-notebook) including the lack of testability and reproducibility of the notebooks among others.

The best practice is usually to keep your pipeline node functions [pure](https://medium.com/better-programming/what-is-a-pure-function-3b4af9352f6f) (where applicable), meaning that they don't incur any side effects. The way notebooks work generally contradicts with that principle.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Kedro doesn't support this but [Ploomber](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber) does (disclaimer: I'm the author). Tasks can be notebooks, scripts, functions, or any combination of them. You can run locally, Airflow, or Kubernetes (using Argo workflows).

If using a notebook or script as a pipeline task, Ploomber creates a copy whenever you run the pipeline. For example, you can create functions to pre-process your data and add a final task that trains a model in a notebook, this way you can leverage the ipynb format to generate reports for your model training procedure.

This is how a pipeline declaration looks like:

```yaml
tasks:
  - source: notebook.ipynb
    product:
      nb: output.html
      data: output.csv

  - source: another.ipynb
    product:
      nb: another.html
      data: another.csv
```

Resources:

- [Repository](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber)
- [Exporting to Airflow](https://soopervisor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/airflow.html)
- [Exporting to Kubernetes](https://soopervisor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kubernetes.html)
- [Sample pipelines](https://github.com/ploomber/projects)